# Placeholder styles from styles.css is not reflecting in component forms

Tags: css, angular, placeholder

My requirement is to apply the below placeholder style for all of my application form input boxes.

```
::placeholder { 
  color: #283d4a;
  opacity: 0.5; 
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

This style is getting applied in browser only if provided in individual component's css file.  When the same is given in styles.css, the styles don't apply.  angular.json has styles.css file included in styles array and other styles from this global file are getting applied.  Still need to include rules for vendor specific selectors like -webkit-, -moz- and -ms-.  So, I'm looking for DRY option to apply common style across the entire application forms.  Can anyone please help me in achieving this requirement?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Had you checked above styles are applied to any element ?, May be its overridden. Inspect element and check in dev tools, For testing purpose add any other styles and check whether is it applying

Comment: @Malathy please use `input::placeholder` for all input placeholder style.

Comment: Placing input::placeholder in styles.css still does not reflect the changes in individual component.

Answer (score -2):

HTML

```
<input placeholder="Type something here!">
```

CSS

```
    input::placeholder {
      color: #283d4a;
      opacity: 0.5; 
      font-size: 14px;
    }
```

Comment: May I know the reason for down votes. It would be helpful for me to learn as well.